# Mysql: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, usercake

Using usercake, I added an extra field to the registration page to record a users interests and store it in a table called interests.

Since I not storing in the same table I needed to create a separate query like the following. Please take note that the user supplied data in being turned into an array.

Here is my query:

```
//add interests1
                $interestsArray = explode(',', $this->interests);
                $interests1 = $interestsArray[0];
                $interests2 = $interestsArray[1];
                $interests3 = $interestsArray[2];
                $interests4 = $interestsArray[3];
                $interests5 = $interestsArray[4];
                $this->interests1 = sanitize($interests1);
                $this->interests2 = sanitize($interests2);
                $this->interests3 = sanitize($interests3);
                $this->interests4 = sanitize($interests4);
                $this->interests5 = sanitize($interests5);
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."interests (
                    interest
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    ?
                    )");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $this->interests1);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /path/models/class.newuser.php on line 218
```

But there is not line 218 in the code... leaving me confused. I am hoping to eventually store each variable in the array in the column on separate rows.
What do you guys suggest?

A link to the whole class if it helps is here: [linktocode](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ebc72ca106033ca0181f)

Comment: your link to the class user, not newuser

Comment: its the correct file. Also I looked at the related searches, my I check the tables and columns and everything seems correct. Nothing seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$stmt might be `FALSE` due to database errors for some reason, e.g. no connection, no database selected by `USE`, table does not exist aso. Check for database errors and write them into a log.

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  // log somewhere mysqli_connect_error()
}
else
{
  if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT ..."))
  {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $this->interests1);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
  else
  {
    // log somewhere $mysqli->error;
  }
}
```

Comment: apparently I needed to add the database name in front of the prefix. Thanks for showing me how to troubleshoot

Comment: Either so, what is in my opinion the best way, or you can execute the `USE databasename` statement once before and then you *can* omit the database prefixes in front of table/entity names.